# Prevent SBT from starting interactive mode

Tags: sbt

I like to enter commands while the previous command is still running. When the command completes, my shell will immediately execute the next.

This is no longer possible with modern incarnations of SBT. If you enter anything while SBT is running, it will assume you want to execute what you've entered in SBT's interactive mode.

This is very annoying.

```
$ sbt test
...
[info]
[info] Passed: Total 348, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 348
[success] Total time: 17 s, completed 18/01/2018 4:19:49 PM
> git status
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: git (similar: exit, plugin, set)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: git (similar: ivySbt, target)
[error] git status
[error]    ^
>
```

Can I reconfigure SBT so that the process *always* terminates after the batch has completed and does not switch to interactive mode?

Comment: What did you invoke before the `git status`?

Comment: I invoked `sbt test` from the shell. In short, I typed `sbt test[enter]git status[enter]`.

Comment: Which version of sbt are you using? `[Enter]` going into shell was implemented in sbt 0.13.15, and was quickly removed in 0.13.16. The current stable version sbt 1.1.0 I don't think should behave this way.

Comment: I guess you can guess which version I have locked down in `project/build.properties` ... `0.13.5`.